# TinyMCE container inherit CSS class from element

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any way to apply css class to whole tinyMCE container without explicit code after load or force it to inherit the classes from element it is applied to?

If you have for example textarea

```
<textarea id="foo" class="myClass"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('textarea.recipe-material').tinymce({
          //some property here to force tinyMCE to inherit myClass in container
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use to add the textarea's classes to tinymce container

```
textarea.tinymce({
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function(event) {
            var class = editor.getElement().className;
            editor.getContainer().className += ' ' + class;
        });
    }
});
```

The setup init attribute isn't in the documentation but works fine with tinymce 4